# How to make a query that brings the results of the day

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have this query but I want to bring the results processed on the day and if there is no data in excess on the day bring the last 100 processed.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_classe where classe>= '2019-10-15';
```

Comment: Why there's Python tag?

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `order by` and `limit` (in both Postgres and MySQL):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_classe
ORDER BY classe DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

I'm not sure what 2019-10-15 has to do with the query.  You seem to want the 100 most recent entries.

Comment: And if I don't have data processed I want to bring the last 100 that are in the bank.

Answer (score -1):

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_classe WHERE classe>= '2019-10-15' ) = 0 
THEN
    SELECT TOP 100 * FROM tbl_classe ORDER by classe DESC, id DESC
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM tbl_classe where classe>= '2019-10-15';
END
```

As per David's request (code seems pretty self-documenting to me..)

- Count the number of records for the chosen date.
- If the count is zero then get the 100 most recent records.
- If the count is > zero then return the records for the day

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.